# Git 'fatal: No such ref: HEAD'

Tags: git, tortoisegit

A weird thing happend to my git repository. When I try to commit something in tortoisegit window I receive all files from project. I cannot revert them, when I pull from server I receive `fatal: No such ref: HEAD` and `fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'HEAD'`. All my local branches are missing. Is there any way to resolve the problem?

This is not first commit or something. This thing happend suddenly.

EDIT:

`git branch -a` says: `Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref`

`git status` prints all project files marked as new file.

I changed repository folder name for a while, and when I changed it back things were not correct.

Comment: What did you do when this happened? Can you show the output of `git status` and `git branch -a`?

Comment: Just for the avoidance of all doubt, by repository folder do you mean the folder named `.git`?

Comment: No, a project folder, which contains .git directly

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: TortoiseGit 1.5.8.0 
git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You've lost your `HEAD` so you'll need to recreate it. The simplest thing to do is this.

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Now you should be able to run other git commands and see where you're at.

(Although, in theory, you could attempt to do `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master` newer git versions don't recognize a `.git` as a git repository unless it already contains a `HEAD` so this won't work to create a new one.)

Comment: Ok, I made like you wrote. After echo I was on master branch, I made commit and was able to switch to my main branch. But now when I try to switch to any of my local branches I receive 'error: pathspec '812' did not match any file(s) known to git.'

Comment: @szaman: I don't know but it looks like the missing `HEAD` wasn't the only thing that's corrupt in your repository. Can you restore it from backup or re-clone?

Comment: I resolved it... nearly. After I applied your tip I watched repo log. There was only last commit missing, so I created new branch based on last 812 which I found. Now I can switch to it. Files from last commit I can take from copy of broken repository, because I was working on 812 when this crash happend. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: ty. I somehow accidentally added "o\n" to HEAD through vim fugitive plugin. your answer helped to find that file.

Comment: WHere do I need to write this?

Comment: @BoldijarPaul you can run it under your project directory with .git inside.

Comment: btw, replace `master` with your branch name, echo ref: refs/heads/your_branch_name >.git/HEAD

Comment: You've lost your HEAD so you'll need to recreate it. > love it.

Answer (score 7):

`HEAD` is usually a reference to a particular branch; in your case, it seems the branch pointers have gone missing, so the HEAD reference cannot be resolved.

You can use `git fsck --lost-found` to scan the object cache for unreachable objects; specifically, you are interested in commits, which can then be found below `.git/lost-found/commit/`; these are pointers to your branches, all you need to do then is find out which is which, and create new references using `git branch`.

Comment: Did you use the `--lost-found` option?

Comment: Did it create the `lost-found` directory?

Comment: Yes it created it but in commit folder is much less files than I had local branches

Comment: You will be missing all branches whose head is a parent commit for another branch. The `git fsck` command will find commits that are not pointed to by either another commit or a branch pointer, so if one branch is on top of another, then there is a commit object referencing the other branch tip, so no reference is created.

Answer (score 6):

I think this answer maybe helpful for someone.
I resolved this problem nearly.
First what I did was, like Charles Bailey wrote, use

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Then my branch changed to master. I commited changes and was able to switch to my main branch. The problem was that I wasn`t able to use any of my local branches. Especially I wanted to work on branch 812. So I found last commit to branch 812 (create message when commit is very helpful ;)) and switched to it. Next I created branch 812 based on the one I switched to. Unfortunately some files were missing. Luckily I had them on the broken repo which I copied before 'echo'

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that on Mac OS X either the 'uchg' or 'uappnd' flag was set, locking some git files regardless of the perms.  I reset the chflags like this and it solved it for me:

```
sudo chflags -R 0000 .
```

Comment: I had permission issues on Linux too.

Comment: yeah, GNU/Linux will respect the chflags when it mounts HFS+