# git clone username problems. warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout

Tags: git, git-branch

Im using terminal to clone my squarespace repository. Im using this code and suffering some username and password problems

```
my-iMac:~ Beast$ git clone https://my-url.dev.squarespace.com/template.git
Cloning into template...
Username: 
Password: 
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

I cant enter any username or passwords. Nothing appears when i type in a UN or PW fields.

warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout. What does this mean exactly. I googled it and still didnt understand fully. :(

I have been following the SS page of http://developers.squarespace.com/using-git/

With not huge knowledge of GIT, I know i have installed it correctly etc.

Any help in getting this warning sign rid of would be fantastic. thanks

Comment: You can specify username and password as per the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-give-username-and-password-when-do-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: doesnt seem to work that

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout)

Comment: As @pva notes, this is probably a branch problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you experience is due to nonexistent master branch in remote repository. Better explained here:

[warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout)

Comment: This helped me – I marked the above question a duplicate.