# Clone a github repo into a private gitlab repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am trying to pull a repo from github and push it up to a private repo on a gitlab server that I am running.

I cloned the github repo to my local machine

```
git clone  https://github.com/somepage/someproject
```

at that point I added a new remote (my gitlab)

```
git remote add gitlab https://mygitlabserver/mypage/myproject
```

then I pushed (in this case only branch on githab was develop)

```
git push gitlab develop
```

Now I am running into problems when I try to clone from my gitlab repo:

```
git clone https://mygitlabserver/mypage/myproject
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: 140, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
remote: Total 140 (delta 40), reused 140 (delta 40)
Receiving objects: 100% (140/140), 2.75 MiB | 1.85 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40/40), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Not 100% what that warning is about, but I am sure its not good.  If I list the contents of that cloned dir its empty.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15631690/6309 can help too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you are getting that error because the default configuration of a repository in gitlab is to have a default branch name of `master`.  You have only pushed a branch named `develop`, and when you clone the repository git is attempting to checkout the nonexistent `master` branch.

You can:

- go into the repository settings in gitlab and set the default branch to `develop`,
- or you can just name the branch `master`,
- or you can provide `-b develop` to the `git clone` command,
- or after cloning you can simply `git checkout develop`.

Comment: You are correct.  Seems like gitlab has no idea what to do if the default branch is not master.  Thanks!