# Git Push Branch Other Than Master

Tags: git, git-branch

I've looked for a solid answer on this, and haven't really found anything relevant. We are working with a remote git repository where we are pushing branch that is not master to the remote repo. For example:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add --all .
git commit -m "changes"
git push remote new_branch
```

However, when we try to clone from that bare remote repository, we get the error:

```
git clone /path/to/repo.git 

warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

I'm not sure why HEAD is detached and not pointing to the last commit on new_branch? How can we clone this remote repository?

Comment: Is the name of your remote "remote"?

Comment: Does `remote` have a master branch? Perhaps you want to [change the default branch on remote](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-default-git-branch-in-bare/)?

Comment: What does the output of `git branch -a` show, if anything, for `remotes/origin/HEAD` (or whatever the name of the remote is)?

Comment: Yes, the name of the remote repo is "remote". The remote repo does not have any repository on it, we are essentially pushing a brand new repo remotely to it. There is no master branch we are pushing up to the remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.` means that the remote (bare) repository contains branch reference in the file `HEAD` that does not match any published branch in the same repository.

**Note that the warning only means that git didn't do checkout.** The cloned repository is otherwise just fine. Just do `git branch -a` to see possible branches and `git checkout the-branch-you-want` to workaround the issue.

This usually happens because the default contents for that file is `ref: refs/heads/master` which says that if somebody is going to `clone` this repository, they should by default clone the branch `refs/heads/master`. By default Git will create local branch without the `refs/heads/` prefix (that is, `master` by default). Try `git help symbolic-ref` for more information.

The problem with this situation is that Git does not provide a method for modifying *remote* symbolic refs so either you use something the Git hosting provider has implemented (e.g. Settings - Default branch in GitHub if you have admin rights) or you have to use branch name `master` as the default branch (because that's the default value for that symbolic ref).

One way to hit this issue is to create a new remote bare repo with no commits and then do `git push name-of-the-remote my-special-branch-name` which will result in bare repository containing a single branch `my-special-branch-name` but the `HEAD` symbolic ref still contains the default value pointing to `master`. As a result, you'll get the aforementioned warning.

see : [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout/15631690#15631690)

Comment: At what point are you not plagiarising? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout/15631690#15631690

Comment: @flafoux you did end your answer by saying "see: this post", however you copied the original post verbatim across many paragraphs.  If you do verbatim quotes, especially of this magnitude, you need to make clear that you are quoting, not summarizing in your own words.  And once you do that--by say, putting quotes around everything you wrote, it becomes clear that you essentially have a link only answer, since you have not summarized the source, so that this should not be an answer.

Comment: @DWright I would have mark this as duplicate but didn't found out how... If I just reply with link : people say I need to put the content, others says I don't have to, other plagia.....

Answer (score -3):

remote repo can be cloned with either of the below commands

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

let me know the exact command your trying to help you better.