# failed to clone a Gerrit Repository

Tags: git, gerrit

I use SSH to clone Gerrit Repository, but unable to checkout caused by "remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref". BTW, There are not a local repository, so, how do you clone repository by ssh command line.

Because I can't edit the remote repository, I even haven't the .git directory. The only things I can do is using different commands to clone remote gerrit repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by limits of authority. I have not the right to access the gerrit project. I will apply the right to access it and try again.