# How to detect if HEAD points to an unborn branch?

Tags: git

How can I detect if the current HEAD is an unborn branch?

"git rev-parse HEAD --" outputs

```
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
```

But git also outputs this for all other inputs like "git rev-parse noHEAD --".

"git branch" returns an empty output.

Do I have to read .git/HEAD and check if the contents start with "ref: " and the reference does not exist?

Comment: you could look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4848607/2082964, apparently `git branch -a` should say: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref. This might help you further?

Comment: what is your git version?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.5 (msysgit on Windows)

Comment: what does `git branch -a` give you? nothing that can help you further? otherwise I don't have another idea than parsing .git/HEAD :)

Comment: "git branch -a" is also empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But git also outputs this for all other inputs like "git rev-parse noHEAD --".

The difference is that `HEAD` must exist, by definition, in a repository.

If you have a `HEAD` that is not a valid revision, then it must be pointing to a branch that is yet to be born.

For example:

```
> git checkout --orphan newbranch
> git rev-parse HEAD --
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
```

Versus if you have a branch checked out:

```
> git checkout master
> git rev-parse HEAD --
```

Versus if `HEAD` is nonexistent or damaged:

```
> git rev-parse HEAD --
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: You can fix a missing head like this `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`